# custom error for jquery file upload input validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am adding an additional field to allow the user to specify a photo caption before uploading. I want to make this filed a required input. I can;t find anything in the documentation the provides validation. So i have put together the following code

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function(e, data) {
                var inputs = data.context.find(':input.form-control');

                if (inputs.val() == "")
                {
                    return false;
                }


            });
```

This allows me to check the value being passed by the caption field and asses it. if I return false it does stop the the form submitting. but it disables the upload button and this can't be re enabled.

Also I can't find a way of displaying an error message to the use.

Am I going about this the wrong way? is there in fact an method for doing client side validation on the additional form data that i have missed?

Thanks

EDIT

I forgot to mention in the main post. I am using the component https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Where do you handle the form submit? In a separate function, bound to the .submit() event? Then, you could move this to a named function (eg SubmitPhoto()) and call it when the form validates. Then, to prevent the submit button from going into a disabled state, edit your code (in your question) and add e.preventDefault(); to the beginning.

Comment: The form submit is handle by the jquery file upload plugin. I am using the callbacks supplied to try and do some rudimentary validation.

Comment: Already has an answer for your question in this topic: [Jquery file upload plugin: how to validate files on add?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549094/jquery-file-upload-plugin-how-to-validate-files-on-add)